# RubyGems refuses to update from 1.3.1 to 1.3.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can't update the rubygems from 1.3.1 to 1.3.5. I've tried the following commands with no luck(logged in as the root)

```
gem update --system

gem update rubygems

gem update rubygems -v 1.3.5

gem install rubygems-update -v 1.3.5
```

The response for the first three command is

```
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update
```

while for the last one the response is

```
ERROR:  could not find gem rubygems-update locally or in a repository
```

Also the current rubygem fails to install some required gems such as 'geokit'. Could the problems be related?

Current Ruby version 1.8.5 on CentOS 5.0

Comment: This might sound silly but do you have `http://gems.rubyforge.org/` in your remote sources?

Comment: @theIV great catch! the cloud platform where I'm hosting set their own server as remote source. added gems.rubyforge.com as source and now works like a charm! thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad it was only that and not something a lot more complicated! :D

Comment: I posted the answer as a community wiki so you can accept it ... solutions in general should not be in comments, this will help people later on find this and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound silly but do you have gems.rubyforge.org in your remote sources?

Comment: would have preferred if theIV has given this answer, since he's the one pointed this out.